# Query is taking so long

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code which takes 25 seconds to show data on screen.

Any ideas on how to make it work with `isset` instead of `in_array` ?

I think this could go a lot faster !

```
if (!$matches[0]['match_id']) $matches = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($matches); $i++) {

    if (in_array($matches[$i]['match_id'],$validMatches)) {

    $match_stats = $db->get_by_fields('player_match_stats', array('match_id'=>$matches[$i]['match_id'], 'player_id'=>$pid));
        if($match_stats['points']!='') $ret[0]++;
        $ret[1] = $ret[1] + $match_stats['points'];
        $ret[2] = $ret[2] + $match_stats['threepoints'];
    }
}

if ($ret[0] != 0) {
    $ret[3] = $ret[1] / $ret[0];
    $ret[3] = number_format($ret[3], 1);
}

return $ret;
```

Comment: Having database queries in a loop is usually not the best idea.

Comment: databases are good at filtering and selecting based on criteria so there's no need to attempt to do it in your code. Show the table structure `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}`, some sample data, and the data you expect as a result. Edit your question to include this. Welcome to SO.

Comment: without a query it's hard to help you. You probably can do this query in MySQL without any loops in your code. Also check your indexes in your table.

Comment: How are you doing with this task?

Answer (score 0):

Few notes from me:

1. Don't use count in `for` loop. It calculates length every iteration. Use foreach instead if you have array.
2. Use `array_intersect` to retrieve all valid matches from `matches` array before your loop.
3. Remove your loop outside of query and retrieve all records from database at once using `WHERE id IN (12,13,15,16,...,77)`. Then iterate over your results.